# Force XSD.exe to use same runtime version

Tags: visual-studio-2010, command-prompt, vb.net-2010, xsd.exe

while generating classes using XSD.exe from VS2010 (cmd prompt) the classes created used Runtime 4.0.30319.18444

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <auto-generated>
'     This code was generated by a tool.
'     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.**18444**
'
'     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
'     the code is regenerated.
' </auto-generated>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType:="date")> _
        Public Property SomeDate() As Date
            Get
                Return Me.someDateField
            End Get
            Set(value As Date)
                Me.someDateField= value
            End Set
        End Property
```

After couple of weeks i regenerated classes again Runtime used was different?
Runtime Version:4.0.30319.1022 and the "value as Date" in set removed. I haven't run any updates since last year so not sure how the Runtime version changed?

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' <auto-generated>
'     This code was generated by a tool.
'     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.**1022**
'
'     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
'     the code is regenerated.
' </auto-generated>
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------


  <System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType:="date")> _
        Public Property SomeDate() As Date
            Get
                Return Me.someDateField
            End Get
            Set
                Me.someDateField= value
            End Set
        End Property
```

How do i ensure the same runtime is used all the time?